# If $2f(x)+3f(\frac {1}{x})=\frac {4x^2+6}{x}$ and $f^{-1}(x)=1$ then find the value of $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, systems-of-equations, functional-equations, fractions

If $2f(x)+3f(\frac {1}{x})=\frac {4x^2+6}{x}$ and $f^{-1}(x)=1$ then find the value of $x$.

My Attempt: 
$$2f(x)+3f(\frac {1}{x})=\frac {4x^2+6}{x}$$
$$2f(x)+3f(\frac {1}{x})=4x + \frac {6}{x}$$

At this point, I couldn't get other idea except comparing the corresponding terms. please provide any other method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are trying to find the following:

$$f^{-1}(x)=1\implies x=f(1)$$

Plugging $x=1$ into the original functional equation...

$$2f(1)+3f(1)=\frac{4+6}1$$

$$5f(1)=10\implies x=f(1)=2$$

Comment: why is $x=f(1)$? How is it?

Comment: @occasionaluser what does it mean to say $f^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: It means replacing $y$ in the place of $x$?

Comment: @occasionaluser which is the same as getting $f(1)=x$

Comment: and, why did you put $x=1$ in the given function?

Comment: @occasionaluser so that I could find $f(1)$

Comment: Can we write like this, 
$$f^{-1}(x)=1$$
$$\frac {1}{f} (x)=1$$
$$x=f(1)$$??

Comment: @occasionaluser no, but like this:$$f^{-1}(x)=1\\f(f^{-1}(x))=f(1)\\x=f(1)$$

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the following system.

$2f(x)+3f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{4x^2+6}{x}$ and $2f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+3f(x)=\frac{\frac{4}{x^2}+6}{\frac{1}{x}}$,

which gives $f(x)=2x$.

Answer (score 1):

Replace $x$ by $\frac1x$ in the original identity and you get another identity:
$$
\textstyle 2f(\frac1x) + 2f(x) = \frac4x + 6x
$$
Now you have two equations for two unknowns -- namely, $f(x)$ and $f(\frac1x)$. Solve these and obtain
$$
f(x)=2x.
$$
Finally, if $f^{-1}(x)=1$, then $x=f(1)=2$.

Comment: what is the main objective of replacing $x$ by $\frac {1}{x}$???

Comment: This is one way to get an explicit form for $f(x)$. The original equation involves both $f(x)$ and $f(\frac1x)$, so this new equation allows you to eliminate $f(\frac1x)$.